# Web Application needs to remember object states - Suggestion for solution needed

Tags: java, javascript, object, servlets, state

I am building a software system, which is using Javascript to display an editable queue of server task (say program xyz is doing stuff on the server one task at a time).

1. Browser UI (O-O JavaScript and JQuery)
2. AJAX
3. [missing technology in question]
4. Linux PHP (Scripts that trigger the app to run)

Now the UI QUeue works great, but if someone closes their Browser, the state of the JavaScript Queue UI Application gets lost (all the tasks that the program on my linux box should peform)

So how to realise this? Would I need a Web application that is running as a service on my RedHat server communicating with the Object Oriented JavaScript App I wrote. The server tasks are already commandeered through PHP.

Is this possible with PHP? I want to avoid having a database at this time. A Java/Tomcat solution also springs to mind. What do you think? Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: "I want to avoid having a database at this time" why ? Its the normal mechanism to persist data. But yes java can store state on server, php too and in a vareity of different ways

Comment: Ok in that case, I am open for a DB solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to persist the queue state on the server at least to memory and preferably to disk too. To represent in memory create two classes `Queue` and `QueueEntry` the former being composed of the latter. If you only persist to memory you will lose queue state if the server process restarts - so write out to disk if you want to maintain state through a restart. Assuming Java, do the necessary to make those classes [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and write out to disk using a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) to avoid contention.

**Update to Reflect Using a DB**

Instead of serialization, have a table of queue entries. Add a column to indicate order - most likely insert date.

Comment: Nice solution. What would be the most elegant way to do this; without contrainsts on language, DB selection, etc.?

Comment: If you're using an OO language then the objects can be written in that, if not objects I would probably use an array of hashes. As for serialization - which is there to solve your constraint of no DB - most OO languages have some sort of serialization built in (see PHP serialization: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) else you need to roll your own format - most likely XML or JSON.

Comment: PHP docs say: "Using serialize to save an object will save all variables in an object". That's a bit too vague for my taste. Will be the references to the values saved or the values of the vars themselves? Storing objects and their states in a DB sound very nice - I guess with MySQL I will have to use serializable as well, or do have a suggestion for an object oriented db?